# Getting Results from External Intent on Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to get data back into my application after launching the intent of an external application? In other words, if the external intent processes some data, is there any way to get that data back into my application?

I assume that the answer is no, but I'd like to double check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the section ["Starting Activities and Getting Results" of the Activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html); it is possible if the other Application supports that.

> When an activity exits, it can call `setResult(int)` to return data back
>   to its parent. It must always supply a result code, which can be the
>   standard results `RESULT_CANCELED`, `RESULT_OK`, or any custom values
>   starting at `RESULT_FIRST_USER`. In addition, it can optionally return
>   back an `Intent` containing any additional data it wants. All of this
>   information appears back on the parent's `Activity.onActivityResult()`,
>   along with the integer identifier it originally supplied.